# How to get the python interactive shell output of a python code in a variable?

Tags: python, io, output, python-interactive

Suppose I have

```py
code = '2+3'
```

I want to run this code in python interactive shell and get the output string in a variable.
So the result of the execution of `code` would be stored in another variable called `output`

In this case, the output variable would be '5'.

So is there any way to do this?

```py
def run_code(string):
    # execute the string
    return output # the string that is given by python interactive shell
```

!!! note:

```
  exec returns None and eval doesn't do my job
```

Suppose code = "print('hi')"
output should be 'hi'

Suppose code = 'hi'
output should be

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

Comment: You're looking for [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: also consider `ast.literal_eval()` slightly safer than the eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really must run strings as python code, you COULD spawn another python process with the `subprocess.Popen` function, specify `stdout, stderr, stdin` each to `subprocess.PIPE` and use the `.communicate()` function to retrieve the output.

python takes a -c argument to specify you're giving it python code as the next argument to execute/interpret.

IE `python -c "print(5+5)"` will output `10` to stdout

IE

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", code], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution I was looking for. I would actually put it into a function and return the decoded stdout and stderr. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is the built in python function

```
eval(string)
```

Comment: eval("print('h')") does not return anything. I am looking for something, that will always return the output. Whatever output in in stdout